# Rails, download progress bar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've looked at a number of resource for creating an download progress bar in Rails.

Any Rails people actually have a working example of successfully implementing download progress bar?

Comment: what do you want to achieve? a download progress bar could e.g. be pure javascript (and therefore not rails related)

Comment: unless he routes the stream through the rails server which I wouldn't recommend.  still not sure why you'd implement something that browsers already have?

Comment: have you checked http://railsillustrated.com/screencast-file-uploads-progress-in-rails-passenger.html ?